# vertical alignment of text element in SVG

Tags: svg, vertical-alignment, w3c

Let's say I have the SVG file:

```
<svg width="1024" height="768" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <text x='20' y='60' style="font-size: 60px">b</text>
    <text x='100' y='60' style="font-size: 60px">a</text>
</svg>
```

I want to somehow align the top of `a` and `b`. Actually, I want my positioning to be according to the `roofline` instead of `baseline`!

Comment: The only answer that works in IE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29089222/9069356

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The `alignment-baseline` property is what you're looking for it can take the following values

```
auto | baseline | before-edge | text-before-edge | 
middle | central | after-edge | text-after-edge | 
ideographic | alphabetic | hanging | mathematical | 
inherit
```

Description from w3c

> This property specifies how an object is aligned with respect to its
>   parent. This property specifies which baseline of this element is to
>   be aligned with the corresponding baseline of the parent. For example,
>   this allows alphabetic baselines in Roman text to stay aligned across
>   font size changes. It defaults to the baseline with the same name as
>   the computed value of the alignment-baseline property. That is, the
>   position of "ideographic" alignment-point in the
>   block-progression-direction is the position of the "ideographic"
>   baseline in the baseline-table of the object being aligned.

[W3C Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#AlignmentBaselineProperty)

Unfortunately, although this is the "correct" way of achieving what you're after it would appear Firefox have not implemented a lot of the presentation attributes for the SVG Text Module (['SVG in Firefox' MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/SVG_in_Firefox))

Comment: Had no luck with that. Could you provide an example?

Comment: In my opinion the best answer, as it answered mine without having to navigate to a wall-of-text page.I wanted to display my text at y = 0, but it was off screen, so I used a CSS rule "alignment-baseline: hanging", and it did exactly what I was looking for, text at highest point in the SVG container, without a single pixel being offscreen.

Comment: @SeMeKh: Hmm incidentally, it worked for me on Chromium, but now I just verified that the same doesn't not work on Firefox. So it appears this property is not supported consistently across browsers as of now.

Comment: @R.Hill Looking at the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/SVG_in_Firefox) it appears your correct "Various presentation attributes don't work (alignment-baseline, ...." updated answer to reflect this fact.

Comment: @SeMeKh "alignment-baseline: hanging" seems to work on firefox. What exactly didn't work there?

Comment: `text-before-edge` apparently doesn't register with Firefox.

Comment: @R.Hill Here is the bugreport for firefox which was opened over 11 years ago https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=308338 Btw: What is the difference between 'middle' and 'central'?

Comment: In HTML "middle" is vertical alignment, and "center" is horizontal alignment. I'm not sure they are the same in SVG however.

Comment: Upvoted by mistake, and because I've made the same mistake before, I can't undo it. ☹ `alignment-baseline: central` does _not_ work for SVGs in FireFox, and that seems to be by design. `dominant-baseline: central` works in every browser I've tried so far, as indicated in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15997503/1450294

Comment: The more upvoted `dominant-baseline` seems to be by far the better answer, in that it actually works cross-browser, even in 2021.

Answer (score 290):

According to SVG spec, `alignment-baseline` only applies to `<tspan>`, `<textPath>`, `<tref>` and `<altGlyph>`. My understanding is that it is used to offset those from the `<text>` object above them. I think what you are looking for is `dominant-baseline`.

Possible values of  `dominant-baseline` are:

> `auto | use-script | no-change | reset-size | ideographic | alphabetic | hanging | mathematical | central | middle | text-after-edge | text-before-edge | inherit`

Check [the W3C recommendation for the **dominant-baseline** property](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#DominantBaselineProperty) for more information about each possible value.

Comment: This fixed my problems with Firefox (which was not working with the "alignment-baseline" property). The "dominant-baseline" works on Chrome & Firefox. Thanks!

Comment: Except that this doesn't work in any version of IE at this point, so it's really not that useful for many real-world applications, unfortunately.

Comment: Since IE doesn't support either dominant-baseline, or alignment-baseline, you can check support for the feature like so `element.hasAttribute('dominant-baseline')`, and if it returns false apply `dy=-0.4em` as outlined in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29089222/2296470

Comment: dominant-baseline: central worked in my case. thanks!

Comment: none of these seem to actually vertically center bare svg text... it's close, but not quite spot on...

Comment: be aware that [dominant-baseline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558060(v=vs.85).aspx) is not supported by IE10-12 **and** Edge16

Comment: `dominant-baseline:central;` in my <style> block aligns my <text> element's numeric values to be perfectly centered on their y coordinate.  A shame Edge still doesn't support it.

Comment: works nicely with transformations & scaling - https://jsfiddle.net/wbqrv1cu/ (at least in Chrome)

Answer (score 55):

attr("dominant-baseline", "central")

Comment: This aligns by the center of the character (as much as the font glyphs play nicely), not sure how this is an answer here to this question.

Comment: This is d3 or jquery method of assigning attributes

Comment: This solution puts the baseline in the vertical centre of the text. So the y coordinate is at the vertical centre. This was the answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: The core of the answer is correct - set dominant-baseline attribute to central, however attr() is not a native JS function and there is no explanation at all.

Comment: The question was asking for a "rooflike" alignment, not "central". I assume the correct `dominant-baseline` value that actually answers the original question is `hanging`.

Answer (score 36):

If you're testing this in IE, dominant-baseline and alignment-baseline are not supported.

The most effective way to center text in IE is to use something like this with "dy":

```
<text font-size="ANY SIZE" text-anchor="middle" "dy"="-.4em"> Ya Text </text>
```

The negative value will shift it up and a positive value of dy will shift it down.  I've found using -.4em seems a bit more centered vertically to me than -.5em, but you'll be the judge of that.

Comment: Thank you for having the only answer that works in IE. It's a shame we have to do this, but the other answers wasted me a significant amount of time getting everything working in Chrome/FF, then finding that it doesn't work in IE during browser testing.

Comment: Nice and simple decision! And we should remember to remove "alignment-baseline" attribute to omit its influence on the text position in browsers which support it.

Answer (score 6):

After looking at the [SVG Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextElementDYAttribute) I've come to the understanding that the baseline properties are meant to position text relative to other text, especially when mixing different fonts and or languages. If you want to postion text so that it's top is at `y` then you need use `dy = "y + the height of your text"`.

Comment: Appreciate the link to the spec, some really useful reading there. Wasn't aware of the (linked) `"<list-of-lengths>"` option for instance (allows per-character manipulation)