# How to get the dimensions of a D3.js element before drawing it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm using a combination of AngularJS and D3.js to dynamically draw line graphs based on data retrieved from an API.

Below is a picture of my y-axis. As you can see, I have a drawn a black vertical line representing 0 to 100%. I have 5 tick marks labelled with their associated percentages.

[image]

Here is the code that generates this:

```
    var yScaleIntervals = 4;
    var yMaxlabel = 100;
    for (var i = 0; i <= yScaleIntervals; i++) {
      var tickY = self.yBottom - (self.yPixSpan  * (i/yScaleIntervals));
      var tickLabel = ((100 * i)/yScaleIntervals).toString() + '%';
      console.log("tickY = ", tickY);
      self.svgContainer.append("line")
        .attr("x1", self.yScaleX - 2)
        .attr("y1", tickY)
        .attr("x2", self.yScaleX)
        .attr("y2", tickY)
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        .attr("stroke", "black");

      var YfontOffset = 30;
      var XfontOffset = 4;
      var label = self.svgContainer.append("text")
        .attr("x", yScaleX - YfontOffset)
        .attr("y", tickY + XfontOffset)
        .text(tickLabel)
        .attr("font-family", "Courier New")
        .attr("font-weight", "bold")
        .attr("font-size", "10px");
        .attr("fill", "black");

    }
```

As you can see, I have hardcoded `YfontOffset` and `XfontOffset` to re-position the text to appear somewhat adjacent to those tick marks.

But this is not what I really want. I want each text label to appear the same number of pixels to to the left of their associated tick marks. And I want the tick marks to be exactly horizontally in the middle of the text. Thus the `x` and `y` attributes of each label must be computed based on the bounding box of the text. How can I get the dimensions of those bounding boxes before the text is drawn on the canvas so I can use them to in those attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I get the dimensions of those bounding boxes before the text
>   is drawn on the canvas?

In short, you don't.  Just change your order of operations, draw them and then move them:

```
  var YfontOffset = 30;
  var XfontOffset = 4;
  var label = self.svgContainer.append("text")
    .text(tickLabel)
    .attr("font-family", "Courier New")
    .attr("font-weight", "bold")
    .attr("font-size", "10px");
    .attr("fill", "black")
    // using translate, so I can set the 
    // x/y in one attr call
    .attr("transform", function(d){
       var bb = this.getBBox();
       return "translate(" + fancyCalcX() + "," + fancyCalcY() + ")";
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Skip bounding boxes altogether and use text-anchor

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor

```
.style("text-anchor", "end");
```

Comment: But I have to change the Y position of the text, not just the X.
"text-anchor" seems to only change the X positioning. Also, I don't just need  it at the text-anchor "end" position. I need to be shifted further to the left.

Comment: To be shifted further to the left, just keep your little XFontOffset value. For the y-positioning use the css property `alignment-baseline` or if it has to be for IE too, use the `dy` attr and a `em` unit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250403/vertical-alignment-of-text-element-in-svg