# D3 dynamically vertically align text

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I've seen a few post here about using `dy` to vertically align text, but all of them just pick a random value without explaining it. Surely this value would differ depending on the font size? My text's font size is stored in a variable (`fsize`), and its value can change depending on other factors. I tried setting `.attr("dy", fsize / 2)` (not quite exactly that since `fsize` is a string and in ems, but you get the point), and my text is way off centre. What value should I choose, given a font size of `fsize`?

Comment: could you provide an example ? JSFiddle maybe

Comment: @thisOneGuy My code's too big for a fiddle, but I can give you a picture if you like.

Comment: Yeah that would be ok maybe

Comment: The `y` attribute of a `text` element specifies the y coordinate of the bottom of the text. The `dx` attribute offsets the text above or below that mark. When you are offsetting by `fsize / 2`, you are offsetting by half of the entire height of the text (the height of a *capital* letter, not lowercase). If you want lowercase text to be centered, you should use `fsize / 4`.

Comment: @JSBob My text is numbers, which, I think, are about as high as a capital letter. Anyway, even if they were lowercase, this still doesn't make sense, as my text is waaaay off: http://i.imgur.com/IPVr0tI.png

Comment: OK, so for some reason `fsize / 2` it works perfectly if I set my font size in pixels rather than ems (i.e. `fsize` is a number). Does anyone have any idea why that is?

Comment: Also, don't forget about `alignment-baseline` [css property](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12250444/16363)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Surely this value would differ depending on the font size?"

if you use 'em' units it shouldn't matter what the font size is as they're a relative-size unit

https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/css2em.htm

So you can use rules of thumb like `.attr("dy", "0.7em")` which shifts text y-wards by 70% of the font height