# Vertically/Horizontally Center Text inside a SVG Path

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, graphics

I would like to vertically/horizontally center a text inside a rectangle made with a SVG `Path` element.

By center I don't mean having my first letter at the center of the rectangle but having the center of my text at the center of the path.

Here is my code structure:

```
<svg id="shape">
    <path id = "a" d="M 0 0 L 100 0 L 100 100 L 0 100 Z"></path>
    <text>
        <textPath xlink:href="#a">My Text</textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: I've managed to do it horizontally with a text-anchor and coordinates attribute. but I'm still searching for the vertical way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15997503/1038015

Comment: just saw this one thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to achieve that by doing something like this:

```
<svg id="shape">
    <path id = "a" d="M 0 0 L 100 0 L 100 100 L 0 100 Z"></path>
    <text x="50" y="50" text-anchor="middle" alignement-baseline="middle">My Text</text>
</svg>
```