# Vertically align an image inside the svg

Tags: html, css, image, svg

How could I vertically align an image inside an `svg`?

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250403/vertical-alignment-of-text-element-in-svg) and it did not help. As you can tell from [the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6u957dtL/3/) attempt the `dominant-baseline: central;` does not work or I am doing something wrong.

Will be grateful for any help provided.

Code:

```html
<svg style="background-color:#f1fe96; border: 1px black solid;">
  <image href="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/plant-growing-picture-id510222832" width ="50" height = "50" style="dominant-baseline: central;"/>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: dominant-baseline is a text property, it has no effect on images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the height of the image to 100% (or whatever height you want to center the image in) and additionally set the attribute `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"`.

```html
<svg style="background-color:#f1fe96; border: 1px black solid;">
  
  <image href="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/plant-growing-picture-id510222832" width="50" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"/>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#ImageElement and https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute