# Vertical alignment in SVG via svgwrite

Tags: python, svg, inkscape, svgwrite

I'm having issues with vertical alignment of texts when using the svgwrite python library.

For example, here's a simple code that generates a red-filled circle with a black text saying "Text" on top of the circle:

```
import svgwrite                                             

d = svgwrite.Drawing(filename='alignment_test.svg',                          
                     size=(60,60))                                             
circle = d.circle((30,30), 30, fill='red')                                     
text = d.text('Test', (30,30),                                                 
              style='text-anchor:middle',                                      
              font_size='17px')                                                                                                               
d.add(circle)                                                                  
d.add(text)
d.save()
```

The result is this expected image:

[image]

However, I want the text to also be vertically aligned.

I tried using the `alignment-baseline` attribute of SVG, i.e.

```
style='text-anchor:middle;\
       alignment-baseline:middle'
```

However, it doesn't work - neither in FireFox (where the vertical alignment just doesn't work), not in Inkscape, which complains `Unimplemented style property 363`.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to solve the matter.

Answer (score 1):

...so while writing this question I searched around a bit more, and actually read the *second* answer here (by toutankh):
[vertical alignment of text element in SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250403/vertical-alignment-of-text-element-in-svg),
which suggests using the attribute `dominant-baseline` instead of `alignment-baseline` for text objects. And it works perfectly.

Lesson learned: never read only the first answer to a SO question.