# Consistent rendering of SVG textbox text position?

Tags: svg, browser, alignment, w3c

I guess this is similar in spirit to [vertical alignment of text element in SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250403/vertical-alignment-of-text-element-in-svg) - consider this `test.svg`, which I made in Inkscape (with some manual text edits afterwards), where I just placed a "text box", by choosing the Text tool, and dragging it while the mouse is pressed, so it draws a rectangle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   width="110"
   height="80"
   viewBox="0 0 110 80"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg12"
   sodipodi:docname="test.svg"
   inkscape:version="1.2.1 (9c6d41e410, 2022-07-14)"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="namedview14"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:showpageshadow="2"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
     inkscape:deskcolor="#d1d1d1"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="2.9362515"
     inkscape:cx="67.432916"
     inkscape:cy="27.245623"
     inkscape:window-width="1280"
     inkscape:window-height="657"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1" />
  <defs
     id="defs9">
    <rect
       x="5"
       y="5"
       width="100"
       height="70"
       id="rect_shape_textbox" />
  </defs>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       id="text_texbox"
       style="font-size:12px;line-height:1;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;dominant-baseline:hanging;white-space:pre;shape-inside:url(#rect_shape_textbox);display:inline"><tspan
         id="tspan671">Hello Texbox</tspan></text>
    <use
       xlink:href="#rect_shape_textbox"
       id="use_rect_shape_textbox"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#00FF00;stroke-width:1;stop-color:#000000" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Inkscape handles the "text box" by having a `<rect id="rect_shape_textbox">` in `<defs>`, and then using `shape-inside:url(#rect_shape_textbox);` in the `style` attribute of the `<text>` element; I have made this rect visible with `<use>`. I have also deleted the x and y attributes from both the `<text>` and its child `<tspan>`, that Inkscape otherwise inserts.

Inkview (from Inkscape Inkscape 1.2.1 (9c6d41e410, 2022-07-14)) renders `test.svg` like this:

[image: test.svg inkscape]

... while Firefox 115 renders this (Edge 114 is pretty much the same):

[image: test.svg firefox]

I have discovered, that Inkscape totally ignores attributes x and y on `<text>` and its child `<tspan>` if `shape-inside:url(#rect_shape_textbox);` is used, only `dominant-baseline` style attribute seems to matter - while browsers seem to take `<text>` or its child `<tspan>` x and y attributes into account as well (if both are specified, then `<tspan>`'s x and y "win", and parent `<text>`'s x and y are ignored).

So, I'm thinking, in order to have an SVG with "text box" (one which uses `shape-inside:`) render consistently in both browsers and inkscape, I should allow either the `<text>` or its child `<tspan>` have x and y attributes, and use these x and y to manually finetune the text position solely for browsers (considering that Inkscape otherwise ignores them).

Is there a better approach than this - as in, one where one could possibly avoid having to manually fine tune attributes?

Comment: Keep your inkscape svg as an editor/master file and save another file as a browser version via **svg-optimised** format option. **In 2023 no browser supports this "text box" concept** based on `shape-inside`. It is not made up – but there is no guarantee this will ever be supported for SVG text elements in the near future. SVG has quite a **long history of discontinued multiline text or textbox concepts** that never found their way to final specs or browser implementations. So you'll find a lot of w3c pages describing promising text box concepts – ignore them!

Comment: Many thanks for that, @herrstrietzel - feel free to  post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it - I think it definitely explains the situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can position SVG elements with `<animateMotion>` on a `<path>`

You can create this all in SVG without JavaScript (take the SVG output from the SO snippet below)

```
<text alignment-baseline="middle">Line #
  <animateMotion dur="1s" fill="freeze" keyPoints="0;.2" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear">
    <mpath href="#verticalline" />
  </animateMotion>
</text>
```

All you have to do is recreate this for **every line** and set the `keyPoints` value

Not sure if InkScape does SMIL animation, it for sure won't run JavaScript

But with JavaScript (in a native Web Component) its easier to create:

```html
<svg-text-align in="BOX" duration="2">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 110 80" style="background:pink;height:180px">
    <template id="BOX">
      Line #1
      Line #2
      Line #3
      Line #4
    </template>
    <rect id="BOXRECT" x="5" y="5" width="100" height="70" fill="lightgreen" stroke="green" />
  </svg>
</svg-text-align>
<script>
  customElements.define("svg-text-align", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => { // let innerHTML SVG parse
        let id = "#" + this.getAttribute("in");
        let box = this.querySelector(id + "RECT");
        let x = ~~box.getAttribute("x") + 5;
        let y = ~~box.getAttribute("y");
        let h = ~~box.getAttribute("height");
        let svg = `<path id="${id}LINE" stroke="red" d="m${x} ${y}v${h}"/>`;
        let lines = this.querySelector(id).innerHTML.split("\n").filter(x => x.trim());
        let dur = this.getAttribute("duration"); // set to .001 for "instant" display
        let startpoint = .15; // todo calc based on line count
        let step = 1/lines.length;
        svg += `<g fill="blue" font-size="15px" font-family="arial">`;
        svg += lines.map((line, idx) => `<text alignment-baseline="middle">${line}
            <animateMotion dur="${dur}s" keyPoints="0;${startpoint+idx*step}" 
                           fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear">
              <mpath href="#${id}LINE" /></animateMotion></text>`).join("");
        svg += "</g>";
        box.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", svg);
      })
    }
  });
</script>
```